# How do I programmatically translate a Drawable Gradient?

Tags: android, xml, gradient, drawable

The linear gradient which I am trying to create programatically:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient
    android:type="linear"
    android:centerX="50%"
    android:startColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:centerColor="#99FF8A8A"
    android:endColor="#FFF8F8F8"
    android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

I wrote this code:But I didn't get the same result.

```
GradientDrawable _gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable(
        GradientDrawable.Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, new int[]{
        Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"),
        Color.parseColor("#99FF8A8A"),
        Color.parseColor("#FF8F8F8")
});

myimage.setBackground(_gradientDrawable);
```

Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

To do this in code, you create a GradientDrawable.

The only chance to set the angle and color is in the constructor.

If you want to change the color or angle, just create a new GradientDrawable and set it as the background.

```
View layout = findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);

    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
            new int[] {0xFF616261,0xFF131313});
    gd.setCornerRadius(0f);

    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
```